# how to get directory name by inode value in c?

Tags: c, bash, unix, filesystems, directory

i am tring to add a new feature to bash
and the job need a func to get the directory name  from the given inode value
so how to got this work? i mean if there's some builtin func in bash's source code
if not , any help will be accept

Comment: Is the inode the inode of a directory you want the name of, or is it the inode of a file in some containing directory which you want to know the name of?

Comment: You do realize that a given file can be in several different directories, don't you?

Comment: Could you give an example of how you might use this feature (and how it is useful)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the directory and get the inode of `..` then list that and find the name of the file there that has the inode you are looking for.

Comment: How do you list the directory if you only know the inode?  (That's significantly different than having a file descriptor.)

Comment: @ephemient: Whoops. I guess that just seemed like such a <i>useful</i> thing that I assumed you could do it without being in the kernel.

Comment: well its this, i am a chinese, and my linux system was configure to zh_CN.utf-8 lang, but as you know windows's default encoding is not this, and once i have use scp to copy files from windows to my linux server,then hold the original encoding, so it will display mass on my linux server, i think i can use ls -i to display all file or directory's inode value , then use cd -i inode_value to enter a directory that display mass

Comment: this answer closed to my destination

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible without searching through the filesystem for a dir that contains a file with the given inode. Filenames are named references to inodes with no backlinks.

Comment: N.B. btrfs has/will have backlinks.