# Is there a way to open file by known inode

Tags: python

I get an inode for some logging file like '/tmp/logging'
and I want to open it via inode, NOT path.
How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of a brute-force search of the filesystem for the inode (ex, `find / -inum $X`), you can't.

See the discussion here: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Perl/comp.lang.perl.misc/2006-05/msg02223.html

Comment: IIRC not every inode needs to be listed in a directory

Answer (score 7):

In general you cannot do this from user-space because the system routines accept a path as an argument.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606774/why-cant-files-be-manipulated-by-inode) post.

Comment: Ah, nice find — much better than my link. OP, give this (wo)man an accept!