# Is there any way that I can search for a file or a filename using a given inode number?

Tags: c, file, unix, inode

I am taking in an inode number from a user and I have to search the file system for that file.  How do I search through inode numbers. I have to do this using C and unix.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){

    int inodeNumber;
    printf("Please enter the inode you wish to view:\n");
    scanf("%d",&inodeNumber);

    struct stat fileStat;
    int temp_file;
    temp_file = system("find/fs/root -inum inodeNumber");
    fstat(temp_file, &fileStat);
    //printf("Information for %s\n",argv[1]);
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("File Size: \t\t%d bytes\n",(int)fileStat.st_size);
    printf("Number of Links: \t%d\n",(int)fileStat.st_nlink);
    printf("File inode: \t\t%d\n",(int)fileStat.st_ino);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?  Why do you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606774/why-cant-files-be-manipulated-by-inode

Comment: I tried to use the system("find - inum inodeNumer"); but it doesn't seem to work. It just gives me errors. I need this for a class assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse your filesystem's directories recursively, doing `stat` (or probably `lstat`) on each file, comparing `st_ino` member of `struct stat` to the inode number you're searching.

If you didn't have to do it in C, I would recommend `find /fs/root -inum N` instead.

Comment: What if I just wanted to search through the /dev files and not the whole file system. Would that be easier to do?

Comment: How do you traverse the file system?

Comment: You traverse the file system with [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) or [`ftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftw.html).  Restricting the search to `/dev` is simply a question of where you start from.  There are fewer files in `/dev` than in the system as a whole, so it will be quicker, but no easier or more difficult (but there are few plain files in `/dev` whereas there are few character or block special devices outside `/dev`).

Comment: So, my code runs but it just keeps giving me the same file over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `system()` runs the command without any connection to your process beyond it waits for `system()` to complete.  You maybe need to think of using `popen()`?

Comment: I just tried popen, this is what it gives me  `Please enter the inode you wish to view:
123456
sh: find/dev/: No such file or directory
---------------------------
FILE SIZE:   0 BYTES
NUMBER OF LINKS:  191
FILE INODE:   15774463
File Permissions:  -rwxr-xr--
`

Comment: `find/dev/` lacks a necessary space character, should be `find /dev ...`

Answer (score 0):

Anton is right in general if you need to support all OS, but if you are using ext4 there is a faster way:

```bash
function fd_to_inode() { cat /proc/self/fdinfo/"$1" | grep ino: | awk '{print $2}'; }
function path_to_device() { df --output=source "$1" | tail -n 1; }
sudo debugfs -R "ncheck $(fd_to_inode 4)" "$(path_to_device .)"
```

```
debugfs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Inode   Pathname
67771103    /home/fred/Downloads/bash-5.2.9/example
```

Internally, it uses these functions:

```c
errcode_t ext2fs_open_inode_scan (ext2_filsys fs, int buffer_blocks, ext2_inode_scan *scan)
```

> Initialize the iteration variable scan. This variable is used by ext2fs_get_next_inode. The buffer_blocks parameter controls how many blocks of the inode table are read in at a time. A large number of blocks requires more memory, but reduces the overhead in seeking and reading from the disk. If buffer_blocks is zero, a suitable default value will be used.

```c
void ext2fs_close_inode_scan (ext2_inode_scan scan)
```

> Release the memory associated with scan and invalidate it.

```c
errcode_t ext2fs_get_next_inode (ext2_inode_scan scan, ext2_ino_t *ino, struct ext2_inode *inode)
```

> This function returns the next inode from the filesystem; the inode number of the inode is stored in ino, and the inode is stored in inode.
>
> If the inode is located in a block that has been marked as bad, ext2fs_get_next_inode will return the error EXT2_ET_BAD_BLOCK_IN_INODE_TABLE.