# Why is iget() hidden in xv6

Tags: pwd, getcwd, xv6

I'm playing a bit with [xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6.html), a modern implementation of Unix version 6.

For my first hack, I wanted to implement the simple `getcwd` syscall, but I'm a bit lost as to which level of abstraction I should use.

- Should I use the `struct file` interface?
- Or maybe the `struct inode` interface?
- For what matters, it seems it could even be implemented purely in userland.

I started implementing it with `struct inode` manipulations. My naive idea was to retrieve the `proc->cwd`, then `readi()` its second entry (`..`), scan it to retrieve my previous `inum`, and so on recursively until I hit the root.

Doesn't seem very performant, but that will fit for a first hack.

My problem though is that I need `fs.c:iget()` to retrieve a `struct inode` from the `inum`s I get in the `dirent`s. I've noticed that `iget()` is static in `fs.c` and not declared in `defs.h` which annoys me a bit, but I can't find the reason why.

So, this is my question. Why is it that `iget()` was deliberately hidden from the rest of the kernel?

Comment: I think you should really try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just created a post there, but I guess it's far less visited than the main stackoverflow.

Comment: True, but I doubt most users here are working with Unix. Linking to your other post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126261/why-is-iget-hidden-in-xv6

Comment: Well, the post on unix.stackoverflow was flagged as offtopic :/

Comment: Sorry about that, I am not helping much here. I guess you have already found it, but you can try: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ and similar forums. I don't really know where Linux experts roam. Good wikipedia article on xv6 though with heaps of links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xv6

Comment: Writing as a comment instead of an answer because I am not that knowledgeable on the topic. Found several web pages pointing to the [content found here on iget()](http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/0710.1/0812.html) not certain exactly how relevant it is, but it appears that it might have bad error handling, also read that perhaps deliberately hidden to keep people from using it. I think emailing: Russ Cox (rsc@swtch.com),
Frans Kaashoek (kaashoek@mit.edu) or
Robert Morris (rtm@mit.edu) would be your best bet to get the correct answer (bottom of page on your first link). Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me they were just pragmatic.

iget is used only by the directory manipulation routines.
The directory manipulation routines are in fs.c.

As for the getcwd implementation.
It would be much better if you follow the chdir syscall code.
The path is there.
You just need to store it, probably in a new field in the proc structure.
Of course, if the path given is relative, you should append it to the current stored path.

Comment: Okay, I will take that. And thanks for the pointers to `getcwd` :)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion answer to Your question is:

1. it was insecure and non generic. (if You could access directly file via inode, without traversing dirent's, how would security be mantained? You need permission for a file as well as execute for parent directory)
2. it was inconclusive to access file by inode (file with same inode might be in several directories, and inode number is unique just for given FS)

but perhaps I misunderstood You ? Regarding how to get cwd, I'm pretty certain You'd prefer pointer to solution so maybe this will help:

1. what is being kept in u.u_dent.u_name ?  (take a closer look at user.h)

You might want to take a look at these too:

http://lwn.net/Articles/254486/

[Why can't files be manipulated by inode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606774/why-cant-files-be-manipulated-by-inode)

[how to get directory name by inode value in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605851/how-to-get-directory-name-by-inode-value-in-c)